# C# From a string[] to Char[][]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

I tried many option from what i could find here and on MSDN but none seems working. 
So basicly i have to read a file, and then turn the content to char[][]
for example : 
file:

```
ABCD 
EFGH 
QWER
```

Need to become :

```
{ { 'A','B','C','D' },{ 'E','F','G','H' },{ 'Q','W','E','R' } }
```

And this what i did so far:

```
private static char[][] ParseFile(string file)
    {
        string[] fileOne = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        char[][] fileOut = {};
        char[] fileOutLine;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileTwo.Length ; i++)
        {
            string linew = fileTwo[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < linew.Length; j++)
            {
                //Stuck here
            }
        }

        return fileOut;  
private static char TurntoChar(string s)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
                case "S":
                    return 'S';
                    break;
                case "O":
                    return 'O';
                    break;
                case "F":
                    return 'F';
                    break;
                default:
                    return 'B';
                    break;
        }
    }
}


internal class Point
{
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: `string.ToCharArray` is your friend. (Also, LINQ: `return fileOne.Select(line => line.ToCharArray()).ToArray())`)

Comment: It would have been easier but the problem is i have to avoid     Linq    , Basicly i need only pure c#

Comment: In what way is LINQ not "pure C#"? You should put more details in your question. (It's also not clear why you've got a `Point` question in your question at all.)

Comment: `the problem is i have to avoid Linq` Why?

Comment: @JonSkeet I just need some help to complete this, hint or anything and i would be greatful!

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment. Remember, once you declare/create arrays, you cannot change their size. So the way you declared fileOut will not work - it is an empty array of zero size, and you can't change that, or place anything in it. You need to know the dimensions in advance. Either that, or, if you are allowed, use List<T>, which can be resized dynamically. P.S. As Jon Skeet said, string.ToCharArray is your friend - if allowed, make use of it.

Comment: I've given you two hints already - you said you couldn't use LINQ (which you didn't mention in the question) but you haven't said anything about `string.ToCharArray`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really give lambda a shot. It would make your life way easier.
Well, if you insist then here you go

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"yourpath");
char[][] charArray = new char[lines.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    char[] lineChars = new char[lines[i].Length];
    charArray[i] = lineChars;
    for (int j = 0; j < lines[i].Length; j++)
    {
        charArray[i][j] = lines[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Linq`;

```
var fileOut = fileOne.Select(x => x.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
```

If you don't want to use `Linq`;

```
string[] fileOne = File.ReadAllLines(file);
char[][] fileOut = new char[fileOne.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < fileOne.Length; i++)
{
    fileOut[i] = fileOne[i].ToCharArray();
}
```